# "Science books" vs. "Scientific books"

Tags: adjectives, nouns, modifiers

Sometimes I get puzzled whether to use a ***noun*** "science" or an ***adjective*** "scientific" to modify the following noun. 
>

So, how could you determine, in general,which one is true?
>

Look at these examples

- I would love to read ***science*** ***books***.
- I would love to read ***scientific*** ***books***.

>

- nervous cells
- nerve cells

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your two examples:

- The book itself is not scientific, but its subject is science.
- The cells are not nervous, but are the type occurring in a nerve.

Some more examples which make the use of an adjective absurd:

- A goat living in the mountains is not a **mountainous goat**, it is a
  ***mountain goat***.
- A clasp for the hair is not a **hairy grip**, it is a ***hair
  grip***.

Here are some which defeat the above observations:

- A drum containing oil is an **oil drum**, and is also **oily**.
- A bag made of leather is a **leather bag**, and is also **leathery**.

In the last two examples the adjective *is* applicable, but only as a property of the object. It does not truly describe the object.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your ***first*** example:

*Science* is the name of a subject.

*Scientific* is an adjective that describes something based on or characterised by the methods and principles of science.

So a "science book" would be a book about science.

A "scientific book", if such a book existed, would be a book that in itself follows the principles of science.

Now you might think they are the same thing, but although a book may be *about* science, it isn't actually the product of science. The book wasn't created in a laboratory under scientific conditions. So I would say that calling a book about science a "scientific book" is not strictly correct, although may well be used idiomatically.

That said, the word *scientific* may be used to describe something that was not obviously so if it contained some elements that were based upon science. For example a novel or film that features a fictional story but is based upon real science may be described as "scientifically accurate".

Regarding your ***second*** example:

This is more problematic because while *nervous* is indeed related to the nerves, there are also multiple meanings of both.

I do not believe "*nervous cells*" is correct at all. A single neuron is called a "*nerve cell*". It is not merely *related to* nerves, it *is* a nerve. Nerve cells collectively make up the *nervous system*.